# How can I use something like "discard;" to increase performance?

Tags: opengl, glsl, lwjgl

I would like to use shaders to increase my in-game performance.

[image]

As you can see, I am cutting out the far-away pixels from rendering, using the `discard` function.

However, for some reason this is not increasing FPS. I have got the exact same 5 FPS that I have got without any shaders at all! The low FPS is because I chose to render an absolute ton of trees, but since they are not seen... Then why are they causing lag!?

My fragment shader code:

```
varying vec4 position_in_view_space;
uniform sampler2D color_texture;

void main()
{
   float dist = distance(position_in_view_space, 
      vec4(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0));
   if (dist < 1000.0)
   {
       gl_FragColor = gl_Color;
         // color near origin
   }
   else
   {
      //kill;
      discard;
      //gl_FragColor = vec4(0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 1.0); 
         // color far from origin
   }
}
```

My vertex shader code:

```
varying vec4 position_in_view_space;

void main()
{
   gl_TexCoord[0] = gl_MultiTexCoord0;
   gl_FrontColor = gl_Color;
   position_in_view_space = gl_ModelViewMatrix * gl_Vertex;
      // transformation of gl_Vertex from object coordinates 
      // to view coordinates;

   gl_Position = gl_ModelViewProjectionMatrix * gl_Vertex;
   
}
```

(I have got very slightly modified fragment shader for the terrain texturing and a lower distance for the trees (Ship in that screenshot is too far from trees), however it is basically the same idea.)

So, could someone please tell me why `discard` is not improving performance? If it can't, is there another way to make unwanted vertices not render (or render less vertices further away) to increase performance?

Comment: Just so you know, fundamentally `discard` doesn't do what you think it does. It more or less flags a fragment to be discarded, but the shader continues executing. What you want is to prevent the shader from executing in the first place, so implement this logic earlier (e.g. clipping).

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman In the end, I am attempting to merge vertices into less vertices if they are far away from the camera.

How can I do that? Or actually, that's not a question for the comments, but - Does it actually improve performance?

Comment: Yes, that sort of thing actually happens these days with implementations of GPU tessellation. The last thing you want is a bunch of really small triangles that have an area on screen of about 1 pixel, those are a nightmare ;) The concept you're thinking of is known as Continuous Level of Detail and it definitely improves performance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `discard` will actually prevent the GPU from using the depth buffer before invoking the fragment shader.

It's much simpler to adjust the far plane of the projection matrix so unwanted vertices are outside the render box.

Also consider not calling the glDraw for distant trees in the first place.

You can for example group the trees per island and then per island check if it is close enough for the trees to render and just not call glDraw* when it's not.

Comment: So, if not-rendering the vertices doesn't help, I presume merging the vertices or any other thing that would make detail get less the further away from it I am would not be effective?

Comment: Also, the entire point is that I am experimenting with shaders to see if I can merge vertices or do other similar things to stop lag - Which means I am already aware of the workarounds you said in the answer. I think you are saying that the answer to that is "No", and that ANYTHING i do with shaders will not improve performance. Am I correct?

Comment: once you get into the fragment shader you probably won't be able to improve performance except by making it as simple as possible (uniform control flow and minimal computation)

Comment: Dafuq? Really? What can I do to reduce vertex count before rendering depending on distance, then?

Comment: simplify the tree model for one, you can probably get away with a billboard rather than a full detailed model

Comment: I would like to have vertices near to me detailed and ones far away less detailed..  You're going to suggest two separate tree models, I know, but the main problem is the terrain, which I cannot really reduce the vertex count for, and it means that currently I have got a tiny terrain and have got absolutely no way to make it bigger!